# Iterate a file but taking 5 lines each iteration

Tags: python, multithreading, file, python-3.x

I've created 5 threads to process the lines. I send one line as argument to each thread.

The output is just that I need.  But then it stop by error.

The code:

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import threading

# Create class myThread as subclass of Thread
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, num, myArg):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num = num
        self.myArg = myArg

# Overrides run() method to defines the thread goes to do.
    def run(self):
        print ("I'm thread number: ", self.num)
        print(self.myArg)


myFile = open('file_01.txt', mode='r')

for myLine in myFile:
    for h in range(1, 6):    # create 5 instances of the thread
        t = MyThread(h, myLine)
        t.start()
        myLine = myFile.__next__()

myFile.close()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sajime/PycharmProjects/Learning/iterarFichero.py", line 25, in <module>
    myLine = myFile.__next__()
StopIteration
```

The 'file_01.txt' content is a simple 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...' stuff.

The bug isn't in the multi-threadinig class nor calls, It comes in the iteration of the file, but, why?

For those  who is asking why I need this: The script must process the lines to load data in web forms, and take a lot of time (lags in the server). I realized that if I divide the tasks is more faster. (I don't know if there is a better method to do it)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do. How many lines can be in your file? How many threads do you want? It sounds like you want 5 threads, but it looks like you're creating a thread for every line in the file.

Comment: @Weeble Lines in the file are unkown.  There are 5 threads. Yes, I create a thread for every line in the file, but only 5 threads are working at the same time.

Comment: Why not having 5 threads and send lines through queues? BTW, in Python, strictly speaking only one thread will work *at the same time* even on a multicore machine.

Comment: You are all right, @bereal.  I fixed the bug with the iterator file, but now it crashes by can't open thread error.  I must deal with queues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for count, myLine in enumerate(myFile):
    t = MyThread(count % 5 + 1, myLine)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks @JayanthKoushik That fix the bug with the file iteneration.

Answer (score 1):

with `myLine = myFile.__next__()`, you advance the myFile Iterator. When the iterator is fully consumed, it throws that `StopIteration` Exception as a signal.

You can catch that, and simply break the loop, since you know you're done.

Unfortunately, there is a logic error in your program, too: you advance the iterator after every thread start, but also in the outer loop. That means that after you've started all Threads, the next line will be read into myLine which gets immediately overwritten by the outer loop.

To avoid that (and to have fewer code), you can replace the whole inner and outer loop with something like

```
[MyThread(i%5+1, myLine).start() for i, myLine in enumerate(myFile)]
```

Comment: This will create a long list of whatever `start` returns, `None` probably. No need to use list comprehensions if you don't actually want that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import cycle, izip
for h, myLine in izip(cycle(range(1,6)), myFile):
    t = MyThread(h, myLine)
    t.start()
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Sorry @M4rtini, but I don't understand that code.  I don't know the itertools module.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're calling the 'next' line twice in each loop.

The for loop in your code iterates through the lines by calling next each time. Then you're calling it again within your loop.

Pull out this:

```
myLine = myFile.__next__()
```

To make the final loop:

```
h=0
for myLine in myFile:
    t = MyThread((h % 6), myLine)
    t.start()
    h+=1
```

The % does an integer division to always ensure it fits into the thread indexes!